# How to define object array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

In c# I can write below code;

```
object[] params = new object[4] { "a", 10, "c", true};
```

What is the Java notation of above code?

Comment: Why you want to do this? why array of objects intead of array of strings? I dont think this is efficient approach.

Comment: what do you really want to know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object[] param = new Object[]{ obj0, obj1, obj2, ..., objX };
```

or

```
Object[] param = { obj0, obj1, obj2, ..., objX};
```

or

```
Object[] param = new Object[X+1];
param[0] = obj0 ;
...
param[X] = objX ;
```

Comment: I corrected your index value because if x is 5, then maximum aray index should be 5-1 = 4 . Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`Object[] array = new Object[]{ "a","b"};`

- Note that you do not have to specify the size of array while using this syntax
- The array is filled up with values in the same statement.

OR

```
Object[] array2 = new Object[2];
```

If you do this, then polulate array using

```
array2[0] = "a";
array2[1] = "b";
```

You can also create anonymous array, which is can be used to pass to a method which takes array argument e.g.

```
public void methodTakingArray(Object[] array){
    // perform operations using `array` variable.   
}
```

and you call the method as `methodTakingArray(new Object[]{"a","b"});` so that it can be accessed in the method using `array` local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] params = {"a","b"}
```

or

```
Object[] params = new Object[8];

params[0] = "a";...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" , "g", "h" };
```

Check the difference:

Object instead of object

No [8] : you cannot define dimension if you are initializing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, 
`Object []params=new Object[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" , "g", "h"};`

You can declare any array like this, using the syntax

```
Type [] var_name=new Type[]{/*Values seperated by commas*/x, y, z};
```

Answer (score 0):

> object[] params = new object[8] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" , "g",
>   "h" };  // 8 is no need here

define array as follows

```
object[] params = new object[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" , "g", "h" };
```

Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to learn more about Arrays in java.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple!

As you have started learning Java, I hope you have learned the syntax of Array creation. Array creation in Java is a two step process, unlike C/C++.

Since you have worked in C#, it would be easy for you to learn too:

Syntax:

```
    Array_type Array_name[];
    Array_name = new Array_type[Array_size];
```

So, your solution is:

```
    Object param[];
    param = new Object[8];

    param[0]='a';
    param[1]='b';
    and so on..
```

Ofcourse you can combine these two steps into one, by writing:

```
    Object param[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'};
```

I hope that helped!